# How can I create a plot in LaTeX with a specific curve and labeled axes?

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to create a plot in LaTeX that looks like the attached image. Can someone please help me with the code to create this kind of curve in LaTeX?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried the following code to create the plot:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3, 0) -- (4.2, 0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0, -3) -- (0, 4.2) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[scale=0.5, domain=-3:3, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

I am not very proficient in writing in LaTeX.

Comment: Please [edit] your code into your post.  BTW, pgfplots will add an `axis` environment that will save you from having to create that part yourself.  (And why do your axes go from -3 to 4.2, when no part of your graph is doing that?)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible approach in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  I hope that my drawing is simple enough to be of use as a tutorial example, but you might also like to follow the link above and look the manuals and some of the introductory material.

[image]

This is wrapped up in the `luamplib` package, so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\mplibnumbersystem{decimal}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric period, rate, present_value, future_value;
    period = 20; % years
    rate = 15; % percent
    present_value = 1;
    future_value = present_value * (1+rate/100) ** period;

    numeric u, v;
    5u = 8v = 3.5cm;  % set horizontal and vertical scale

    % curve 
    path ff;
    ff = ((0, present_value) for years = 1 upto period:
        .. (years, present_value * (1+rate/100) ** years)
    endfor) xscaled u yscaled v;
    draw ff withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor 2/3 red;

    % axes
    path xx, yy;
    xx = origin -- (period, 0) scaled u;
    yy = origin -- (0, ceiling future_value) scaled v;
    draw xx; 
    draw yy;

    % scales
    for x = 0 step 5 until period: 
        draw (origin -- 2 down) shifted (x * u, 0);
        label.bot(decimal x, (x * u, -2));
    endfor
    for y = 0 step 2 until ceiling future_value:
        draw (origin -- 2 left) shifted (0, y * v);
        label.lft(decimal y, (-2, y*v));
    endfor

    % axis labels
    label("Years", (1/2 period * u, -24));
    label(textext("Euros") rotated 90, (-24, 1/2 future_value * v));

    % start and finish labels
    label("\begin{tabular}{c} Present value\\" 
          & decimal present_value 
          & " euro\end{tabular}", (1.8u, 2.7v));
    label("\begin{tabular}{c} Future value\\" 
          & decimal (floor(10 * future_value + 1/2) / 10)
          & " euros\end{tabular}", ((period - 2.2) * u, future_value * v));

    % arrow annotations
    path cap, dis;
    cap = subpath (9, 13) of ff shifted (8 * unitvector(direction 11 of ff rotated 90));
    dis = subpath (12, 8) of ff shifted (8 * unitvector(direction 10 of ff rotated -90));
    drawarrow cap; label.ulft("\small Capitalisation", point 2 of cap);
    drawarrow dis; label.lrt("\small Discounting", point 2 of dis);

    % title
    label.top("\large\textbf{Discounting and capitalisation at " & decimal rate & "\%}", 
        point 5/2 of bbox currentpicture shifted 8 up);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

If you don't have `TeX Gyre Heros` installed, then choose a different font, or get it from [here](https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre).